# User rating based on response time in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, rating

For example. Users A posts a product for sell. Users B click to see product and would like to chat with user A. The response time is the time from when user B click on chat button with user A until user A replies.

What I need to do is there're many users like user B and I need to display average response time of users. E.g: user A respond to user B in 2 mins, to user C in 4 mins, so the average response time is 3mins.

Here's my moongoose schemas:

```
var users = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    name:  String,
    averageResponseTime: Number,
});

var userResponseTime = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    userId:  ObjectId,
    respondToUserId: ObjectId,
    responseTime: Number
});
```

#### I need to be able to get and display average response time in user profile page.

#### What's recommended way to calculate and store averageResponseTime value?

I'm thinking to have cron job to runs every 5 minutes to calculate avarage time based on data from `userResponseTime` but I don't like this since it consumes resources

Anyone has experience with this please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please let me know if I can explain the question better.

Answer (score 1):

To display/calculate value you need to get related userResponseTime objects for selected user. 
So here the plan

1. Get all collection data for **userResponseTime**
2. Calculate average response time for current selected user

   ```
     userResponseTimeCollection.find({"userId":{$eq:require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId(userId)}}).toArray(function(err, results) {
       var responseTimes = 0;
       var responseCount = 0;
       var avgResponseTime = 0;

       results.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
         responseTimes += item.responseTime;
         responseCount++;
       });
       if(responseCount > 0)
         avgResponseTime = responseTimes / responseCount;
     });
   ```

Or you can get all data for users, all for their responses, and after that got through loop

```
  var users = [];
  var userResponses = [];

  usersCollection.find({}).toArray(function(err, results) {
    if(results)
      users = results;
  });

  userResponseTimeCollection.find({}).toArray(function(err, results) {
    if(results)
      userResponses = results;
  });

  users.forEach(function(user) {
    var responseTimes = 0;
    var responseCount = 0;
    var avgResponseTime = 0;    
    userResponses.forEach(function(response) {
      if(response.userId == user._id){
        responseTimes += response.responseTime;
        responseCount++;
      }
    });
    if(responseCount > 0)
      avgResponseTime = responseTimes / responseCount;
    user.ResponseRate = avgResponseTime;
  });
```

Maybe it looks overwhelming but hope you got the main idea. GL!

BTW. If you need to keep such data about avg response it's way better to recalculate avg time on pre/post hook for mongoose http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: Subdocs seems to be a good option to accomplish. What I am concerned is performance. With your approach, everytime a new responseTime value is saved, query userResponseTime collection and calculate the average response time. Is it a bad for performance?

Comment: Yeah, I think recalculating this data on pre/post will be faster. And on get you'll just getting value from same collection

Comment: P.S. but this approach will slow down the Save procedure for every record in user collection. Also _id field is already indexed, so it will be fast query. Also you can split big loop for parts of smaller one with **promise**s and load data asynchronously.